# Angular6 polling not returning data

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, rxjs, polling

I have an Angular application where I am trying to check an external data service for changes every few seconds, and update the view.

I've tried to implement Polling from rxjs but I'm not able to access the object, conversely it seems the polling function isn't working but assume this is because the returned object is inaccessible.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  polledItems: Observable<Item>;
  items : Item[] = [];
  title = 'site';
  landing = true;
  tap = false;
  url:string;
  Math: any;

  getScreen(randomCode) {
    const items$: Observable<any> = this.dataService.get_screen(randomCode)
      .pipe(tap( () => {
      this.landing = false; 
      this.Math = Math
     }
    ));

    const polledItems$ = timer(0, 1000)
    .pipe(( () => items$))
    console.log(this.polledItems);
    console.log(items$);
  }
```

excerpt from app.component.html

```
<h3 class="beer-name text-white">{{(polledItems$ | async).item_name}}</h3>
```

excerpt from data.service.ts

```
   get_screen(randomCode) { 
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl + '/tap/' + randomCode)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you want an array of items you could go with something like this.

```
// dont subscribe here but use the 
// observable directly or with async pipe
private readonly items$: Observable<Item[]> = this.dataService.get_screen(randomCode)
    // do your side effects in rxjs tap()
    // better move this to your polledItems$
    // observable after the switchMap
   .pipe(
     tap( () => { return {this.landing = false; this.Math = Math}; })
    );

// get new items periodicly
public readonly polledItems$ = timer(0, 1000)
   .pipe(
      concatMap( () => items$),
      tap( items => console.log(items))
   )
```

the template:

```
// pipe your observable through async and THEN access the member
<ng-container *ngFor="let polledItem of (polledItems$ | async)>
    <h3 class="item-name text-white">{{polledItem.item_name}}</h3>
</ng-container>
```

take a look at: https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-polling/

if you are not awaiting an array but a single  than you dont need the ngFor but access your item_name like:

```
<h3 class="item-name text-white">{{(polledItems$ | async).item_name}}</h3>
```

Comment: I've updated the post, but essentially receiving the same data as before, I just get Observable { .. in my console.

Comment: sorry, ive missed the concatMap in the second observable. allso add the observables as class members(no need to recreate them). your polledItems should be of type Observable<Item[]>. and your console log needs to be inside the observable( other wise it would not be logged when data arrive).

`export class AppComponent {
  polledItems: Observable<Item[]>;
   ...

  private readonly items$: Observable<any> =  ..

  public readonly polledItems$ = timer(0, 1000)
    .pipe( 
       concatMap(() => this.items$),
       tap( polledItems => console.log(polledItems))
     );
  }`